# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: angular, laravel, authentication

I am working on an Angular - Laravel Project, I have Login functionality, when i try to get to the login page, i get this error in the console :

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiOTB.png)

This is my login function in the Usercontroller :

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "email" =>  "required|email",
        "password" =>  "required",
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(["validation_errors" => $validator->errors()]);
    }

    $user           =       User::where("email", $request->email)->first();

    if(is_null($user)) {
        return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "message" => "Failed! email not found"]);
    }

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
        $user       =       Auth::user();
        $token      =       $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json(["status" => "success", "login" => true, "token" => $token, "data" => $user]);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "success" => false, "message" => "Whoops! invalid password"]);
    }
}
```

And this is my token.service.ts :

```
export class TokenService {
  private iss = {
    login: 'http://localhost:8000/api/login',
    };

  constructor() { }

  handle(data) {
    this.set(data.access_token);
    //this.setuser();
  } 

  set(token) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }
  get() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  remove() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  isValid() {
    const token = this.get();
    if (token) {
      const payload = this.payload(token);
      if (payload) {
        return Object.values(this.iss).indexOf(payload.iss) > -1 ? true : false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  payload(token) {
    const payload = token.split('.')[1];
    return this.decode(payload);
  }

  decode(payload) {
    return JSON.parse(atob(payload));
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return this.isValid();
  }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the payload sent from the backend to the frontend which i believe is the token, I am really confused I hope u can help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your token with base64 format on the back-end side.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, can you please point me to where exactly i should do that? i'm guessing the line where the token is created of the UserController in the login?

Comment: can you post here the code you have in createToken($token) method?

Comment: `if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
            $user       =       Auth::user();
            $token      =       $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;

            return response()->json(["status" => "success", "login" => true, "token" => $token, "data" => $user]);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "success" => false, "message" => "Whoops! invalid password"]);
        }`

Comment: I am sorry about the messed up comment, the code is there in my question if this is not clear, i looked up the function to encode which is base64_encode(), should i use this?

Comment: that's not what I wanted to check. this code is already on your question. I asked for the code of createToken() method in your Auth class.
Yes, you need to use base64_encode() to encode your generated token.

Comment: Hello again ! so i found it , here it is `    public function createToken(string $name, array $abilities = ['*'])
    {
        $token = $this->tokens()->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'token' => hash('sha256', $plainTextToken = Str::random(40)),
            'abilities' => $abilities,
        ]);

        return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->getKey().'|'.$plainTextToken);
    }`

Comment: you see this method is provided by Sanctum, so i doubt it has smth to do with it